# Registered tableViewCell doesn't show the text label

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I've created a tableView with a registered Cell with reuseIdentifier as "cell". I've added this tableView to superview as subview.

```
 private let tableView: UITableView = {
    let table = UITableView()
    table.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    
    return table
}()
```

I've comforted the protocol functions for TableViewCellDelegate and DataSource as below. But still when I do run the app it only shows my tableView but not the cells which should write "Hello". Why this might be happening?

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return notifications.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let model = notifications[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Hello"
    
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Even if you conform to the protocol delegate and datasource, do you assign it to the tableView? `tableView.dataSource = dataSourceClass` `tableView.delegate = delegateClass`

Comment: Hi Vollan. Yes I did that in viewDidload of my class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do check with your notifications array is it empty or not if you are fetching it from api make sure to call tableView.reloadData()

have you added your tableView into view ?

Comment: Reload Data was the problem. After adding it right into the function which I fetch the data, it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add code below in the ViewController and it should work

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}
```